# How to put cell(2,2) in user input cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Create a subroutine called WherePutMe that asks the user for a row number and column letter then places the 2,2 position of a selection into that cell. (HINT: Make sure that you select a selection before running the sub!)

HINT: If x is an integer and is equal to 7 and y is a string and equal to "B", you can place z into cell B7 by: Range(y & x) = z. Hope this helps.

```
Sub WherePutMe()
'Place your code here
Dim x As Integer, y As String, z As Variant
z = Selection.Cells(2, 2)
x = InputBox(" What is the row number: ")
y = InputBox("What is the column number: ")
Range(x & y) = z
```

What is my mistake? Please provide simple answer

Comment: *y is a string* so why ask for number `y = InputBox("What is the column number: ")` ? The HINT says `Range(y & x) = z` but your code is `Range(x & y) = z`

Answer (score 0):

- Validate `Selection` is Range object otherwise `Selection.Cells` may raise error
- `Selection.Cells(2, 2)` may out of `Selection` area. eg. `Selection` is `B3:B4`,  then `Selection.Cells(2, 2)` is C4
- Your code is going to update B7, I think it is not necessary to ask users to input row and column number.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WherePutMe()
    Dim iInput, z As Variant
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If Selection.Columns.Count > 1 And _
            Selection.Rows.Count > 1 And _
            Selection.Areas.Count = 1 Then
            z = Selection.Cells(2, 2)
            iInput = MsgBox("Update cell [B7]?", vbYesNo)
            If iInput = vbYes Then
                Cells(7, "B") = z
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Selection is invalid."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Select cells before run the code."
    End If
End Sub
```

- If you prefer to get input from users

```vb
           x = InputBox("What is the row number: ")
           y = InputBox("What is the column letter:")
           If x = 7 And UCase(y) = "B" Then
               Cells(7, "B") = z
           End If
```